# Markov jump process time inhomogeneous holding time question - can someone please check this for me?

Tags: probability, statistics, markov-process

Question and answer are in the following pic:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIJsy.jpg)

(im sorry i do not know how to use mathjax)

Comment: You're going to want to learn MathJax (It isn't too hard; I promise). People are much less likely to even look at your question if it's handwritten and hidden in an image.

Comment: What are Definition 4.6 and Theorem 4.7 from? A published textbook, course notes?

Comment: @Math1000 course notes